# SQL Query to return results based on date

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I am very new to SQL so I apologize for trivial things.

Our company has a ticketing system and it has two tables.

On one table it keeps track of when the ticket was closed. The other tracks when the transaction was posted.

I'd like to create a query that returns all tickets where they are in a CLOSED state but the transaction was posted *after* the ticket was closed.

I have something like:

```
SELECT a.proposal AS "Work Order"
     , a.status_code AS "Status"
     , a.status_date AS "Closed Date"
     , b.tranx_date AS "Transaction Date"
  FROM table1 a
 OUTER 
  JOIN table2 b
 WHERE b.tranx_date > a.status_date
```

Then, ideally, it would return something like...

```
Work Order:    Status:    Closed Date:    Transaction Date:
0001           CLOSED     01/01/2021      01/02/2021
0002           CLOSED     01/01/2021      01/02/2021
```

I know my query/syntax isn't right, I've only been learning SQL for 3 days now.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Strawberry Sorry, I've been criticized for not providing enough information on here so I guess I went over the top.

Comment: it's very unusual there is not a "ticket number" or some other identifier that needs to match in the two tables... matching the tranx_date of all rows to the status_date of all rows in the other table,  seems like there would be semi-Cartesian product, matching rows for different ticket numbers.  i'm also guessing that we might also want a condition something along the lines of   `AND a.status_code = 'CLOSED'` but thats just a guess

Comment: @spencer7593 Ahhh, indeed. I ended up adding a ```WHERE a.status_code = 'Closed'``` and that returned the closed tickets. The Work Order is the ticket number, but I didn't even think that they would need to be joined as well.

Answer (score 0):

In mysql you need  left join

```
SELECT
 a.proposal AS "Work Order",
 a.status_code AS "Status",
 a.status_date AS "Closed Date",
 b.tranx_date AS "Transaction Date"
FROM table1 a
left JOIN table2 b ON b.tranx_date > a.status_date
```

and for left join you need  the ON clause

becuase the use of columns related  to left joined table  work as an inner join

Comment: This was a great nudge in the right direction, thank you! It's returning results, however it's returning it based on the date the ticket was OPENED rather than CLOSED. Now I need to figure out how to have it return the latest entry in the table rather than the first.

Comment: i'm not in your data and you just posted the expected  result   without a clear data sample .. so is possible only answer about the structure and syntax of the query but not for the real result  ..   ..

Comment: No, you're not in my data. Yes, you cleared up the syntax of the query and I thank you for that. And I also stated that I need to figure out the latest return, I did not ask you for that.